# ctime returns NULL

Tags: c

I am using ctime. However it always returns null. so it cores on sprintf line. It worked earlier. So not sure why it is randomly returning null.

I have the following code snippet:

```
int main()
{
 char avp_val[50];

 uint32_t date_value=1477069401;

sprintf(avp_val,"%s",ctime((time_t*)(&date_value)));

  return;
}
```

Comment: Hi there! Programming questions go on StackOverflow.com not here.   Please peruse the help section to learn what is and isn't on-topic for SU.  Voted to migrate.

Comment: Why do you think that `uint32_t` is the same as `time_t`?

Comment: Declare `date_value` to be of `time_t` instead of `uint32_t`

Answer (score 1):

It works for me, but the code is still odd.

I'm not sure why you're using `uint32_t` to store the time. It should be `time_t` (or `int` if you must). Time is not unsigned, it can be negative (I hear there was time before 1970). It also shouldn't be 32 bit; if you do that [you'll run out of time in 2038](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem). Most machines use 64 bit `time_t` these days.

You shouldn't use `ctime` because it reuses the same pointer. I suspect that's why you're doing the `sprintf`, to copy the string. Even better, use `ctime_r` which has you pass in the allocated string.

Here is a much more straightforward way of doing this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {
    time_t date_value = 1477069401;

    char date_str[26];

    ctime_r(&date_value, date_str);

    puts(date_str);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When you have a choice for Unixy 1sec timestamps, you should use 64bit. (There are other time representations to which this advice does not apply e.g. NTP.) But for `ctime(&t)` -- and also `time(&t)` as opposed to `t=time(NULL)` -- you MUST use whatever `time_t` is on your implementation, never larger or smaller. If OP's system has `time_t` 64bit, which I agree 'most' do, then passing `&var` that is 32bit probably causes the problem (and is definitely Undefined Behavior). ...

Comment: ... Also `strncpy` is NOT the right way to copy strings in general. The other `n` routines 'just truncate' (and even that is not _always_ right!) but `strncpy` can copy without _any_ string terminator or add unnecessary and sometimes costly padding; see the standard or any man page. If you have `strlcpy` fine; if you have C11 `strcpy_s` okay; if you know or check the size just use `strcpy`; if you must `snprintf (o,100, "%s", s)` or `sprintf (o, "%.99s", s)`; but NOT `strncpy`.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 So many wrong ways to work with strings, I wish the docs would flag them better. Every right way to work with C strings seems to be non standard or "new", so I'll just go with `strlcpy`... On second thought, I'll avoid bringing up the mess entirely.

Comment: FWIW, POSIX 2008 marks ctime_r as obsolescent, as there's just too many gotchas with implementations in the wild (see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/23875690/75652), recommending to use strftime() instead. Or if you really don't want any localization, you can do something like https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=47802#c14 .